# How to Transform from xml to json in Azure Logic apps using Liquid with duplicated element not in array

Tags: azure-logic-apps, liquid-template

How to get values from xml where objects are duplicated and names of these objects are the same: Here is sample XML

```
<Customer>
               <active>true</active>
               <countrycode>SE</countrycode>
               <customerstatus>
                  <customerstatusid>20</customerstatusid>
                  <customerstatusname>Active</customerstatusname>
               </customerstatus>
               <relatedcompany>
                  <active>true</active>
                  <createdby>Jeremy</createdby>
                  <createddatetime>Jan  9 2015  3:37PM</createddatetime>
                  <modifiedby>Samoson</modifiedby>
                  <modifieddatetime>Jan  9 2015  3:37PM</modifieddatetime>
                  <relatedncompanyid>0070</relatedncompanyid>
                  <relationshiptype>EXT</relationshiptype>
               </relatedcompany>
               <relatedcompany>
                  <active>true</active>
                  <createdby>joker</createdby>
                  <createddatetime>Dec 30 2015 11:43AM</createddatetime>
                  <modifiedby>Gorge</modifiedby>
                  <modifieddatetime>Dec 30 2015 11:43AM</modifieddatetime>
                  <relatedncompanyid>2500</relatedncompanyid>
                  <relationshiptype>EXT</relationshiptype>
               </relatedcompany>
            </Customer>
```

I cannot change that xml, so I am struggling with liquid templates on getting the values
My current solution is:

```
"RelatedCompanies": 
        {
            {% for customer in content.customers %}
                Id" : "{{customer.relatedcompany.relatedncccompanyid}}"
            {% endfor %}
        }
```

But it gets only the first value, so how can I get all the values no matter how many of them in the xml

Comment: @Hury Shen If have a time, can you look at it

Comment: And a sub FOR loop over the relatedcompany elements doesn’t work?

Comment: @Skin no because there is no array

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the entire JSON output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this work after using the below liquid template.

```
{
     "relatedcompany": [
      {% for customer in content.Customer %}
        {
                "relatedncompanyid" : "{{customer.relatedcompany.relatedncompanyid}}"
        },
      {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]